# SASS compile error - LoadError: cannot load such file -- listen/version Use --trace for backtrace

Tags: css, ruby, sass

I am trying to use SASS for the first time, i have installed the latest version but get errors in the terminal

```
stuarts-imac:css stuartcookney$ sass --watch main-style.scss
Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
write main-style.css
LoadError: cannot load such file -- listen/version
Use --trace for backtrace.
```

It compiles the css file but something is broken as any other changes that i make they do not update.. what is wrong?

Comment: have you used --trace for backtrace?

Comment: that came up with an error also.... ive installed scout app and works fine now, ditched the CLI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what fixed it for me and some others:

```
sudo gem uninstall listen --version 2.7.0
sudo gem install listen --version 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 14):

Just tried a mix of some answers, on Ubuntu 21:

First:

```sh
sudo apt-get install ruby-listen
```

And then:

```sh
sudo gem install sass-listen
```

It's now posible to `sass src:dst --watch`

Thank you @dimetrodon, @maxime-lorant and @kevin-mack

Answer (score 9):

Lubuntu fixed with a simple:
`sudo gem install sass-listen`

Answer (score 8):

On Linux Mint 18.1.
You can help it

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-listen
```

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same error. The output with the --trace option will contain something like the following near the top:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- rb-inotify
```

I have no experience with ruby but seems like sass is simply trying to load in a dependency which isn't there. You can use gem to resolve it:

```
gem install rb-inotify
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all above:

- gem install listen --version 2.4.1
- gem install sass-listen
- apt-get install ruby-listen
- gem install rb-inotify
- completely uninstalled sass and ruby and reinstalled.

The only thing that worked was to ditch ruby-sass completely and install [dart-sass](https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass) instead.

Comment: To install dart-sass, `npm install -g sass` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu (checked in Ubuntu 20)

```
sudo apt install sass sass-listen
```