# SASS "LoadError: cannot load such file --listen/version"

Tags: ruby, command-line, sass

I've been struggling with this for hours.

I have

- ruby installer 1.9.3 installed.
- sass version 3.3.1 maptastic maple

every time I run watch command I get

```
            Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.

            Load Error: cannot load such file -- listen/version
```

they addressed a "listen" problem fix on their [blog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html) but I'm still getting this error.

using something like scout app works but I want to get this to work on command line.

any ideas?

edit: The problem is "fixed" when I do this

[SASS compile error - LoadError: cannot load such file -- listen/version Use --trace for backtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329046/sass-compile-error-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-listen-version-use-tr)

It watches and the changes are updated. But it freezes if I try to exit with ctrl+c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in Sass 3.3.1. I've just released 3.3.2, which should fix it.

Comment: I have compass 1.0.0.alpha.18 with Sass 3.3.2 and Susy 2.0.0 and still get Loaderror on line["45"] of C: cannot load such file --wdm

Comment: thanks a ton for the prompt bug fix! i'm the dude who's been tweeting you.

Comment: @Dean_Wilson: can you file an issue on http://github.com/nex3/sass/issues with the full error output when running `sass --watch --trace`?